# Differencies between MLflow deployment possibilities

Tags: mlflow, mlops

Can someone please explain what are the main use cases when deciding how to serve a model from MLflow:

- using command line "mlflow models serve -m ...."
- deploying local Docker container with the same model
- deploying model online for example on AWS Sagemaker

I am mainly interested in differencies between option A and B because as I understand both can be accessed as REST API endpoints. And I assume if network rules are in place then both can be called also externally.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, the main difference is described in the [documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-models-build-docker):

> NB: by default, the ***container will start nginx and gunicorn processes***. If you don’t need the nginx process to be started (for instance if you deploy your container to Google Cloud Run), you can disable it via the DISABLE_NGINX environment variable

And the `model serve` uses only [Flask](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/1de8bc2d7ccf09f908bacf47c5453d47d62db368/mlflow/pyfunc/scoring_server/__init__.py#L205), so it could be less scalable.